# Use a different mediaplayer in an Android App

Tags: android, media-player

For a project of mine I am more or less stuck with the mediaplayer AwesomePlayer. The downside of this player is that the fps is too low and it can't seem to handle the clips well.

Now I went on the playstore and tried out different kinds of mediaplayers and found one that has no problems with the clips and has a good fps. My question hereby is: Is there a way to use a different mediaplayer in my Android App?

-Edit-
A little sidenote: The player must only show the video, not the rest of the gui. There also shouldn't be any user interaction required in order to play a video (Everything will be done in the code).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can also invoke installed Android video player to play the video with just a few lines of code. This example plays a video file from external storage.

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(videoFile);
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(fileUri,                
        URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileUri.toString()));
  startActivity(intent);
```

Intent chooser will show up to let user pick his preferred video player. I wrote a blog to discuss how to do it in detail, http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/20/video-playing-with-android-media-player. Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem with playing the video's is that there should be no user interaction required for it. The application is used for narrowcasting. So it must be able to just start playing video's on start-up. There should also be no UI of the player on the screen.